# How to get content of different versions of a document using CMIS API in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, opencmis, apache-chemistry

We have a document that has multiple (say 3) versions in SharePoint 2013 with version series ID 11275 and following ids for different versions :

Version 1.0 - Document id is 11275-512
Version 2.0 - Document id is 11275-1244
Version 3.0 - Document id is 11275-1633

Using the code :
doc = (Document) session.getObject("11275-512")
InputStream is = doc.getContentStream().getStream()

This gives the content that is stored in document uploaded with version 3.0. That is, We always get content only of the latest version, even if we specify the doc id of earlier versions.

Answer (score 3):

That is a SharePoint bug, which has been fixed in the SharePoint 2013 February 2016 CU.